# Trying to expand arguments for launchdaemon at running time

Tags: bash, shell, launchd

I have launchd running a shell script at a noontime every day. I am trying to pass in the previous date as an argument for that script in the .plist for my launch daemon, but according to stdout and stderr logs, it is failing to run.

I manually run my script now in zshell (and it works fine): `./my_script.sh --optionone $(date -v -1d +"%m/%d/%y") --optiontwo`

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/Users/kanejm/scripts/my_script.sh</string>
    <string>--optionone</string>
    <string>/bin/date -v -1d +"%m/%d/%y"</string>
    <string>--option2</string>
```

My error message says I have too many arguments. I'm assuming launchd is not expanding my argument in the .plist I made.

```
usage: %prog [options]: error: unrecognized arguments: -v -1d +"%m%d%y"`/directory-`bindate -v -1d +"%m%d%y"` -v -1d +"%m/%d/%y"`
```

I have done several configurations that also did not work. Namely, a key `<string>variable</string>` for every white space. I have also tried surrounding the variable in the plist with `$()` and `` to no avail. I could not find anything else looking online regarding variable expansion inside launchd arguments. Perhaps I am tactically going about this the wrong way? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

launchd doesn't parse the arguments like a shell would -- it just treats them as literal strings. It's roughly like a shell would treat the arguments if each one was enclosed in single-quotes. (There is one possible exception: if you set the `EnableGlobbing` key to true, it'll expand filename wildcards.)

If you want shell-style parsing/expansion, you need to run the command through... a shell. Something like this:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/bin/zsh</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>exec /Users/kanejm/scripts/my_script.sh --optionone "$(/bin/date -v -1d +"%m/%d/%y")" --option2</string>
</array>
```

Note that the script name and its arguments are being passed as a single `string`, because `zsh -c` expects the entire command to be executed to be passed to it as a single argument (and then spaces within the command string have their usual function of separating command, arguments, etc). It's equivalent to running this on the command line:

```
/bin/zsh -c 'exec /Users/kanejm/scripts/my_script.sh --optionone "$(/bin/date -v -1d +"%m/%d/%y")" --option2'
```

Also, note that I prefixed the command with `exec` -- this will make `zsh` run the script in the same process as `zsh` (essentially, `zsh` will exit and replace itself with a new shell running the script), rather than having the script run as a subprocess and the shell hang out as a (useless) parent.